# How can a single member SMSF be set up?

Tags: australia, smsf

In a Self Managed Superannuation Fund (SMSF) each member has to be a trustee or a director of a corporate trustee and each trustee or director of a corporate trustee a member. However, a SMSF cannot have only one trustee.

As a SMSF can have between one and four members, what are the options for setting up a single member SMSF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The options for setting up a single member SMSF are to have one of the following trustee structures:

- a corporate trustee with the member as the sole director of the corporate.
- a corporate trustee with the member being one of only two directors of the corporate, where the member is not an employee of the other director unless they are related.
- two individual trustees, provided the member is one of the trustees and is not an employee of the other trustee unless they are related.